# Implementing search engine and integrating it to Liferay

Tags: solr, liferay, web-crawler, search-engine, nutch

I'm on a project that require implementation of a portal and a search engine that should be integrated with the portal. 
I choosed using **Liferay** for the portal but for the search engine there is lack of idea.
I studied how seach engine works and i figured out **three module on a search engine**

1. The crawler
2. The indexer
3. The query engine.

I noticed somme existing solutions for the module: **Apache Nutch for the crawler**, **Apache Solr for the Query engine**. so some research brought me in an article of that forum dealing in coupling Solr with Nuch. the problem is don't know if Solr has a Query Engine for the web user interface side (form). else are Solr and Nutch sufficient tho implement the three module of a search engine? please if anybody has details on the architecture and interactions that should be in place you are welcome.

Comment: plz explain to me, you question is does solr have some kind of web ui for querying?

Comment: @Mysterion yes that was my problem. I digged into research and experienced SOLR bundle. I come now to conclusion that SOLR has part 2 (indexer) and 3 (query engine). but now I have some question does SOLR index a full html document (html found and may be submited by the crawler)? after experience basic tutorial on SOLR i noticed that documents to be index are always xml structured documents. is that right? so a crawler like Nucth is supposed to take html and output that structured document that will be passed then to SOLR Instance

Comment: Also docs could be json, csv or binary format (via SolrJ)

Comment: So SOLRJ is used for retrieving query result from Solr and posting documents to Solr. So to display search result from my customized liferay search form i need to write portlet that lay on SolrJ!? other articles from Google mentioned using Liferay Solr plugin downloadable from liferay Market place; I think this plugin is used to port internal liferay index to our external solr instance. My question is to know if i should write my own portlet to retrieve result from my solr Nutch index and solr liferay index

Comment: if you want to write own portlet - you could. but it's better idea to check if something already exist and you could try to resuse it